# angular + redux/ngrx: state update vs. forms

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, angular2-forms, ngrx

Some context first, I'm using:

- [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) for selectors
- [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) for normalization and **denormalization**
- [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store), which is a reactive implementation of redux, for state management

Now similarly to the [react real world example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/reducers/index.js#L8-L14) I have a slice of state dedicated to entities, which is actually a requirement for `denormalize()` method of normalizr to work, since article can have an `author`, or `media` which could all be entities themselves.

Which means that when I'm selecting, for example, a single `user` from my state, I'm grabbing this global slice of entities, my selector looks something like this

```js
export const getOne = createSelector(
  getAllEntities,
  getDetailId,
  (entities, id) => denormalize(id, schema, entities)
);
```

which is then being "selected" from ngrx/store with

```js
state.map(getOne).distinctUntilChanged()
```

now to fill in my forms I do this (semi pseudo code)

```js
class Cmp {
  form = new FormGroup({ /* whatever */});
  user$ = this._store.map(getOne).distinctUntilChanged();

  constructor(private _store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.user$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.form.patchValue(data);
    });
  }
}
```

with combination of reselect and map/distincUntilChanged I get a new update pretty much anytime *any* entity changes, so consider this situation..

- you visit article id 5, it gets filled in with subscription to the store slice made of global entities slice
- you start editing "`text`" `FormControl`
- someone else changes an user with id 3 and you receive an update over websockets, causing the `subscribe` to trigger (since global entities slice changed) and overriding whatever value you changed while editing, with the value that is currently in the store (the old value)

..and there are quite a few different situation along this websocket that can cause an update update.

Is there any pattern in redux world that solves this, or has anyone in ngrx world had to deal with this? The only sensible thing that comes to my mind is saving whatever value to the store as you are typing, which would require hooking angular reactive forms to store, which is huge pain in the arse, and [ngrx/forms](https://github.com/ngrx/core/issues/12) are not coming anytime soon. But I'm sure someone must've came up with some simple solution already.

Thank you!

**(you can read follow up discussion on [gitter](https://gitter.im/ngrx/store?at=58e403b6f22385553d0be22a))**

Comment: Isn't the problem that `denormalize` is accessing the entities directly, rather than via `reselect`-created selectors? If you were to denormalize in a more manual fashion using selectors, would that solve the problem? Although, you'd obviously lose the schema-based niceties.

Comment: What could work would be to create an extra selector for the values needed for forms only (which are usually primitives with no relations, ie. text), but there are situations this would still have problems with, ie. (next comment)

Comment: imagine you have a user with name and age, you can have at least two situations
- you are editing name, without touching age and somene else updates the same user and changes the age.. since you didn’t actually change it, you want it to update, otherwise the updated age will be changed back to whatever it was before the update once you press save after changing the name
- but if you changed both age and name (and you are still editing name), you don’t want age to change to whatever someone else changed it to, since you intentionally did the change and you want it to be the latest value

Comment: I think you have two problems: the denormalize problem; and the concurrent edit problem. Using selectors instead of denormalize might solve the first. And switching off input/property updates on focus (and back on after save) might solve the second. You could probably do something with [`filter`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter) to switch on/off per-input/property updates. Something to consider.

Comment: I don't think focus is enough, you can have more than one input grouped under one save button.. but what I'm thinking is implementing a custom `patchValue` function, that could update only `pristine` form controls, supposing that `pristine` on `FormControl` does what I think it does.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like something worth investigating.

Comment: @fxck can you provide your input on this discussion after 3 years now still i could not see any solid reference or best practice to use

Answer (score 3):

**Consider storing the state of the form separately from the normalized entities.** For example, your state could contain a property such as `articleEditForm` or something similar. Based on a subscription from your router state to get the id of the article, `combineLatest` with the current state of the store to dispatch an action of type 'EDIT_ARTICLE' with the payload of the article. The reducer would then set the `articleEditForm` property on your store state with article state payload. The original normalized entity would only be updated after a successful submission of the form - possibly using the values from `articleEditForm` or a response from the service the form was submitted to. This approach has the advantage of having the state of the form in your redux store for more sophisticated display and validation scenarios.  The values could be updated in redux on every keystroke, input change, form submission, or whatever meets the needs of your use case may be.

This is overkill for 80% of simple forms - with the alternative to just populate forms directly from the normalized entity in the store (perhaps using .take(1) or using the router state and combineLatest with store to manage concurrency concerns). However, even just using vanilla forms, state is still managed separate from the normalized entities in your store - which is an accurate model of the problem IMO.

Answer (score 1):

So far we are dealing with this problem by updating the store on input blur (so not on every keystroke).

```
class Cmp {
    form = new FormGroup({ /* whatever */});

    constructor(private _store: Store<AppState>) {
        this._store.select(getOne)
                   .take(1) // we don't listen to changes
                   .subscribe((data) => {
                       this.form.patchValue(data);
                   });
    }

    onInputBlur() {
        this._store.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_USER', payload: this.form.value });
    }
}
```

We then add the onBlur event to our input

```
<input (blur)="onInputBlur()" formControlName="firstname">
```

Comment: You should probably use `change` instead of `blur` here: `change` is fired on input blur only if the value has changed

Comment: Yes but `change` is fired on every keystroke which is not what I want.

Comment: It's not, that's `input`. Unless I'm remembering it wrong, `change` and `blur` are very similar but `change` is only fired if the value has changed.